# How to change menu icon gravity in a toolbar?

Tags: java, android

I've changed style for my action bar like that:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyAppTheme</item>
</style>
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/menu_white</item>
   <item name="android:layout_gravity">right</item>
</style>
```

And icon of menu now situated on the center of action bar. How to change it to be from the right?

Comment: you only can create your custom toolbar instead of default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my bad. 
I forgot to resize the image and it caused that kind of problem. Now I've resized image ans it looks pretty well.